# Using bisect functions with a key

Tags: python, binary-search, key-function

While using [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) with a `key` parameter I've noticed that the key function is not applied to the searched value. For example, I want to find the first range in a sorted list of ranges where a start value is bigger than the given number:

```
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> ranges = [[1, 3], [4, 10], [11, 20]]
>>> num = 5
>>> bisect_left(ranges, [num+1, num+2], key=lambda range: range[0] > num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'bool' and 'list'
>>> bisect_left(ranges, True, key=lambda range: range[0] > num)  # this works
2
```

The documentation on `bisect_left` reads:

> *key* specifies a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) of one argument that is used to extract a
> comparison key from each element in the array. To support searching
> complex records, the key function is not applied to the *x* value.
>
> If key is `None`, the elements are compared directly with no intervening
> function call.

What exactly is the reason the key function is not applied to the value to be searched for here? This seems a bit inconsistent with [`insort_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left) where the key function *is* applied to it.

Comment: So you are looking for the index of the first item in `[False, False, True]` that is `>= 5`. That's 3 (i.e. no such item exists). I'm not sure why you conclude that this doesn't work.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Right, the example should've used a list for the value to be searched, updated.

Comment: Okay... in either case you should have used `lambda range: range[0]` without `> num`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Fair enough, although `lambda range: range[0] > num` also works, as demonstrated in the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

In `bisect_left`, *x* is the value you want to *compare against* (it is in the "comparison domain"<sup>1</sup>).

In case the values in *a* (the list of input values) are *"complex records"* you can provide a *key* function to map them from the "object domain" to the comparison domain in order to make them comparable to *x*.

If *key* were also applied to *x* you would have to provide *x* in the object domain, too, which would make the code unnecessarily complicated (i.e. in your example you would have to provide any tuple `(5, y)` where `y` doesn't matter).

On the other hand with `insort_left`, *x* is in the object domain because it is to be inserted in *a*. Then *key* is applied to *x* for the purpose of comparison because it *has to be*.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I made up the terms "comparison domain" and "object domain" for this answer. Don't search for them in the documentation, if you will find them there as well, it will be coincidence.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Raymond Hettinger [in the PR discussion](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/20556#discussion_r508096471):

> I think the API is correct in that it supports typical usage patterns. insort() will insert entire records and bisect() will scan the key field for the first match in a range at or above the key value.

There are more details in that PR and related discussions.

Comment: That seems like a pretty controversial decision. I agree with the last comment in the PR that we're actually looking to find the insertion point for **x** in a list, not **key(x)**.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash *"we're looking to find the insertion point for x"* - Are we? Maybe, maybe not. If you have a list of movies sorted by rating, and you want to know how many have a rating 8 or higher, then you want to search for the rating 8. Why would you want to be forced to artificially create a dummy movie object with rating 8 for that search? On the other hand, if you do have a movie and you want to know where its position would be, you can just trivially convert it to key(x) by applying the key function you have anyway. So the way it actually is, **both** kinds of searches are easy.

Comment: I think most of the time binary search is used to find an *existing element* in a list, so you probably already have the element you want to find. I would rather optimize for the common case and provide a consistent API to the users of the library (i.e. the same pattern for `bisect_left` and `insort_left`). Right now it seems to be causing confusion to some people, apparently.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Maybe that is the common case, I don't know. Raymond seems to disagree. Is it really so much trouble to call the key function on it? I think if it were implemented the other way, having to write an extra "unkey" function would be worse.

Comment: BTW, I like the approach `sortedcontainers` took on this: they just added a separate [method](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList.bisect_key_left) to search by key instead of value.